# d3.js array issues: Invalid value for <path> in line graph

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

Fiddle (updating it now): http://jsfiddle.net/hy6r1peb/

I'm attempting to plot points via line graph based on the following data pulled from a JSON API:

```
 var data = {
        "january": [
            {"total": "31", "date": "2015-01-01"},
            {"total": "19", "date": "2015-01-05"},
            {"total": "4", "date": "2015-01-10"}
        ], "error": false, "status": 200
    };
```

This is my code from the [d3noobs](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/b3ff6ae1c120eea654b5) tutorial. It throws an error on line 1 of d3.js. Where have I gone wrong?

```
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json(URL, function(error, data) {
    if (error) return console.warn(error);
    else {
        data = data.january;
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.total = +d.total;
        });
    }

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

});
```

Comment: can you fiddle your work?

Comment: @Fawzan http://jsfiddle.net/hy6r1peb/

Comment: @Terry The entire problem! :( Submit as the answer and so I can be shamed for all eternity. I'd downvote myself if I could.

Comment: Nah, it's not really a solution since it was just a simple typo ;) but glad it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typo'd and had `d.close` in there when I shouldn't have. Doing this purely to close the question -- all credit goes to Terry for his sharp eyes.

Comment: Since it's just a typo, it is unlikely to offer any new insights. You might want to consider deleting the question altogether to keep the knowledge base clean.